# Keep max N values per row in a Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I need to keep the max N (3) values per row in an Array.

```
a=np.array([[1,2,3,4],[8,7,6,5],[5,3,1,2]])
a
Out[135]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [8, 7, 6, 5],
       [5, 3, 1, 2]])
```

The indexes of those can be identified with np.partition:

```
n=3
np.argpartition(a, -n, axis=1)[:,-n:]
Out[136]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 1, 0],
       [3, 0, 1]], dtype=int64)
```

So, my question is:
How should I keep values from those indices and set to zero others to get:

```
Out[136]: 
array([[0, 2, 3, 4],
       [8, 7, 6, 0],
       [5, 3, 0, 2]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a=np.array([[1,2,3,4],[8,7,6,5],[5,3,1,2]])

n=3
mask = np.argpartition(a, -n, axis=1) < a.shape[1] - n

a[mask] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use your indices as [fancy indices](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) to overwrite the values in a zero array:

```py
import numpy as np

# input
a = np.array([[1,2,3,4], [8,7,6,5], [5,3,1,2]])
n = 3

indices = (np.arange(a.shape[0]), np.argpartition(a, -n, axis=1)[:,-n:])
res = np.zeros_like(a)
res[indices] = a[indices]
```

Then you get

```py
>>> res
array([[0, 2, 3, 4],
       [8, 7, 6, 0],
       [5, 3, 0, 2]])
```